# Casting custom annotation view always returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, swift4

In `viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation` I'm customizing my annotations, primarily I'm changing the image of an annotation on a map. The code below works fine on iOS 11, but devices that are running iOS 10 or below don't display custom annoation image.

When I call `MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "customAnnotation")` on iOS 10 it return an Annotation View, but when I cast it (`as? CustomAnnotationView`) to `CustomAnnotationView` it returns nil. I check in Apple documentation and this code should be supported on iOS 3+.

```
if annotation is CustomAnnotation{
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "customAnnotation") as? CustomAnnotationView
        if annotationView == nil{
                annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "customAnnotation") as? CustomAnnotationView
        }
        guard annotationView != nil else{
                return nil
        }

        annotationView!.passedAnnotation = annotation as! CustomAnnotation
        annotationView!.setUpAnnotation()

        return annotationView
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "customAnnotation") as? CustomAnnotationView
```

will always be `nil` because you are creating a `MKAnnotationView`, not a `CustomAnnotationView`.

Change the line to:

```
annotationView = CustomAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "customAnnotation")
```

Comment: Thanks that solved it, but I still don't understand why did the code work fine on iOS 11?